# Rails / Doorkeeper: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, csrf

I'm using Rails 3.2 with Doorkeeper gem for providing OAuth 2 API for 3rd party. I keep getting this warning when using my REST API from outside of the app:

WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

The client app successfully authenticated via OAuth2. Why do I get this warning, and how to implement this csrf properly for the external API?

Comment: You shouldn't implement `csrf` for stateless APIs. It breaks the entire concept of stateless.

Comment: I haven't implemented csrf for the API, I'm just getting this warning from the Rails. Can I skip the csrf validity check for certain methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `protect_from_forgery` from your ApplicationController (or remove it for calls to the API).

Comment: Removing protect_from_forgery from application controller is not safe as this opens your application to CSRF attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off CSRF protection only for the controller that you want open ... this is safer than removing `protect_from_forgery` from the `ApplicationController`. In this case I'm using the create action as an example ... though you can modify to suit your needs.

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, only: [:create]
  # doorkeeper_for :create
end
```

Uncomment the doorkeeper line if you are authentication via doorkeeper.

The point is to open up only what needs to be opened up ...